# How to make a script that checks if a number is an integer in batch

Tags: batch-file, integer

I'm trying to make a script that requires an integer number, and i need to be able to check if the number is an integer.

Comment: It would be better if you could clarify (as specifically as you can) the question and your approach so far.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to keep the examples at the top; they're just there to show you how to use the function. Also, it's modular so you can just throw it in your code and it will work unless you've already got those variable names used.

```
@echo off
cls
:: This is a positive integer and will return TRUE
Call :isNum 54
echo %retval%

:: This is a negative integer and will return TRUE
Call :isNum -13
echo %retval%

:: This is not an integer and will return FALSE
Call :isNum 15a7
echo %retval%

:: This is a decimal and will return FALSE
Call :isNum 12.7
echo %retval%
exit /b

:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
:: Determines if a string argument is an integer value
::
:: Arguments: %1 - the string to check
:: Returns:   TRUE if the string is an integer, FALSE otherwise
:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
:isNum
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set num=%1

:: Strip the leading negative symbol if there is one
if "!num:~0,1!"=="-" set num=!num:~1!

:: Use all digits as delimiters. If there is anything left, it's not an integer.
for /f "delims=1234567890" %%A in ("%num%") do (
    set new_num=%%A
)

set is_num=TRUE
if not "!new_num!"=="" set is_num=FALSE

endlocal&set retval=%is_num%
```

Answer (score 0):

This script takes advantage of `EXIT /B`:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set /p x=
call :isint %%x%%
echo %errorlevel%

pause
exit /b

:isint
set "arg=%~1"
if NOT "!arg:?=!" == "!arg!" exit /b 1

cmd /c exit /b !arg!
if NOT "%ERRORLEVEL%" == "!arg!" exit /b 1

exit /b 0
```

Returns a `ERRORLEVEL` of 0 if a integer, 1 otherwise.
Even works with `"`, `&` and `/?`.

---

The definition of a ***int32*** is any value from `2^31-1` to `-2^31`. (`2^31` will overflow)